# Gitlab login error: invalid email or password

Tags: gitlab

I installed gitlab on my homeserver, the server is running. I can access the login page but I can't login.

admin@local.host.
5iveL!fe

Error: invalid email or password.

What could be the problem?

Comment: This question helped my issue and it's shown on top of search results.

Comment: well, just for beginners, the local server reference should be 'localhost' and not 'local.host' without the ending dot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
/home/gitlab/github/app/observers/user_observer.rb

Notify.delay.new_user_email(user.id, user.password)
```

to change:

```
Notify.new_user_email(user.id, user.password)
```

Run:

```
root@menht.com ~/gitlab/github $ bundle exec rake db:seed_fu RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. But why is this manual hack required?

Comment: @Adrian It seems that you had forgot to run `bundle exec rake db:seed_fu RAILS_ENV=production`